# How to avoid the "language bar" stealing the focus while clicking an icon in the system tray?

Tags: windows, windows-11, taskbar

In Windows 11, the language bar in the taskbar keeps appearing and disappearing based on the currently focused app:

[image]

vs.

[image]

This causes issues when trying to click on of the icons in the tray area as they will switch positions while double-clicking them:

https://imgur.com/a/Zg1vpDo

How to avoid this?
Is there any way to always show the language bar?

Answer (score 0):

For the Language Bar not to change when switching applications:

- Run *Settings > Time & language > Typing > Advanced keyboard settings*
- Uncheck "Let me use a different input method for each app window".

The effect is immediate.

Comment: The setting is already unchecked on my machine, but the effect still occurs, unfortunately.

Comment: Very strange - I can't replicate the problem. Is Windows fully updated? If yes, try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). Let me know if any problem is reported.

Comment: @Matthias - [Edit] your question to include that vital information